# GUI Bootable USB Creator in Debian Stable

Tags: debian, apt, usb-drive, live-usb, iso

In debian stable, I'm trying to locate a package in the repository that will make a bootable USB from an iso file:

```
apt-cache search 'usb' 'bootable'
```

Output:

```
debootstick - Turn a chroot environment into a bootable image
grub-rescue-pc - GRUB bootable rescue images, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
live-clone - GUI to clone and manage Live-Build USB sticks
makebootfat - Utility to create a bootable FAT filesystem
```

I'm aware of `dd` and also of external applications, but I was hoping the main repository would have at least one GUI utility for accomplishing this task. Perhaps I've searched incorrectly. Please advise.

Comment: Not all ISO files can be bootable when written onto USBs: only those that have been specifically prepared with [`isohybrid`](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid) or an equivalent procedure can. Once that is done, the writing is just a simple block-by-block copy which can be achieved by any disk imaging tool. Are you asking about the preparation step or the writing step?

Comment: For example, Ubuntu has a GUI app in their repository called [Startup Disk Creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_Disk_Creator), that allows you to write any bootable ISO to USB by simply selecting the ISO and the USB device. [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) is another GUI app that works similarly. Yet, I like to use apps from the main repository when I can, but I cannot locate one like these in the Debian repository. @telcoM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you are looking for a GUI utility for the writing step, not the hybrid ISO preparation step.

You have perhaps failed to notice an utility that is quite likely already installed on your system: GNOME Disks (in package `gnome-disk-utility`) can write an ISO file to USB, using its "Restore Disk Image..." function.

The real reason why Ubuntu supplies a dedicated [Startup Disk Creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_Disk_Creator) is the two little radio buttons at the bottom of the dialog. When used with Ubuntu live ISO image, the Startup Disk Creator has the option to create bootable USB media *that includes space for persistently storing documents and settings*, known as *Live USB with persistence*.

This is actually quite a bit more complex operation than just writing the contents of an image file to USB. It also requires specific functionality embedded in the ISO image to be written: the image needs to have been built to use Ubuntu's [`casper`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/casper.7.html) system. Although `casper` seems to be gaining popularity among live-USB-with-persistence implementations, I think it's too early to call it a de-facto standard just yet.

Comment: Very interesting. You know, the last time I used Startup Disk Creator, it seemed like an application in decay. I encountered a bug with it where it would ultimately choose an ISO other than the one I selected! I kept trying to select the Arch iso and it kept on selecting the debian iso instead. I've been on Debian ever since! I'm like, ok I'm easy, whatever . . . Normally, when I install an OS, I end up reporting a few bugs, but not with Debian. Thoroughness has preceded me.

Comment: If you were trying to create a live Arch USB *with persistence*, that might be why it failed: the Arch way of setting up a live-USB-with-persistence is no doubt different from Ubuntu's `casper` and so the Startup Disk Creator failed to find the necessary hooks within the image for setting up persistence. But selecting a different ISO seems a silly way to deal with the situation: an error message explaining "I don't know how to set up persistence for this image of a distribution I don't know about" would have been more honest.